# Passing parameters in Links - Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

In the following code sample I am passing `ID` as a parameter. However, I want to pass `userID` as well as a parameter. So overall I will be passing 2 parameters. How can O do this ?

```
<td>
   <g:link
      url="${fieldValue(bean: gInstance, field: "name")}"
      id="${gInstance.id}" >
      ${fieldValue(bean: gInstance, field: "name")}
   </g:link>
</td>
```

How can I pass `gInstance.userID` as a 2nd parameter in the example above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send extra params like this

```
<g:link url="${fieldValue(bean: gInstance, field: "name")}" id="${gInstance.id}" params="['userId': gInstance.userID]">
    ${fieldValue(bean: gInstance, field: "name")}
</g:link>
```

Comment: How can i retrieve the passed value from the Controller ?

Comment: In controller you can access these value with corresponding name.e.g: `params.userId`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters like the following

```
<g:link controller="controllerName" action="actionName" params="[param1: "param", param2: "param"] class="class">Info to Display</g:link>
```

Comment: Hello, dear friend you are missing closing ] bracket.